# Expression type 'DataRequest' is ambiguous without more context Swift

Tags: ios, swift, response, alamofire, ambiguous

I use Alamofire for my request in this function and I have this error if someone could help me please thank in advance.

> Expression type 'DataRequest' is ambiguous without more context

```
 func report(_ track: Track, completionHandler: @escaping (_ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var headers:[String:String] = [:]
    if AuthManager.defaultAuthManager().isLoggedIn() {
        headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + AuthManager.defaultAuthManager().authToken.token!]
    }
    let params: [String: Any] = ["trackCode": track.code]
    let urlString = Cizoo.APIBaseUrl + CizooScheme.report
    CizooAPI.manager.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: .JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers as HTTPHeaders)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { // Error at this line
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completionHandler(error: nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(error: error)
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Which line throws that error? I don't see the class "DataRequest" anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: It's a the line .responseJSON(completionHandler:

Comment: Odd. Looks like an AlamoFire-specific bug, and I don't know much about AlamoFire.

Comment: Oh ok no problem men :/ !

Comment: what version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: Hi @DiogoAntunes, I use Alamofire 4.0.0

Comment: Well for some reason the compiler is not inferring some types. Which ones, are unclear. Try and set your "let urlString" as URLConvertible

Comment: It's still the same error with URLConvertible type

Comment: Ok thanks @DiogoAntunes it's finally a part of my problem! I resolved it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Alamofire source code you can see that the declaration of the method is:

```
@discardableResult
open func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
{
    var originalRequest: URLRequest?

    do {
        originalRequest = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
        let encodedURLRequest = try encoding.encode(originalRequest!, with: parameters)
        return request(encodedURLRequest)
    } catch {
        return request(originalRequest, failedWith: error)
    }
}
```

Which in your case probably the **urlString** is not conforming to the **URLConvertible** protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !

Finally, It was a concern of type declaration
Here is the code solved :

```
func report(_ track: Track, completionHandler: @escaping (_ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var headers:HTTPHeaders? = [:]
    let params:Parameters? = ["trackCode": track.code]
    let encoding:ParameterEncoding = JSONEncoding.default
    let method:HTTPMethod = .post
    let urlString:URLConvertible = (Cizoo.APIBaseUrl + CizooScheme.report)
    if AuthManager.defaultAuthManager().isLoggedIn() {
        headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + AuthManager.defaultAuthManager().authToken.token!]
    }
    CizooAPI.manager.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completionHandler(nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(error as NSError?)
            }
        })
}
```